# Can I use caching to store heavy page

Tags: asp.net

I am currently working on a very heavy web page(2.1 MB). As my clients are going to access the page inside an Intranet, its loading speed is fine. But I want to make it faster than this. Will caching a page of 2.1 MB help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try it and see.

Actually, page caching will help performance, but do you really need to generate the page that big? You are likely loading way more data than each user will be using on each page load. Figure out how to split it up so it runs faster and consequentially likely more usefull for your users.

Comment: yes my page contains five tabs. User can perform any operation on any tab & that should update rest all tabs. So i have no other option other than loading the whole page i.e No postback. I am using PageMethods to perform the operations

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where the 2.1MB is coming from, and how long it takes pages to be generated in addition to their file weight. Caching would probably help page load time by cutting down query/script execution. Most images, JavaScript, etc. should be cached by the browser after first load.

If you've not already, try using [Yahoo's YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) to identify ways of improving overall speed.

Answer (score 0):

Rarely.

The slow part of most web transactions is the desktop.

2.1M takes time to download.  If the desktop bandwidth is tied up with eBay and Facebook updates, your page will be slow.

Comment: How will animated cursors or Facebook updates on the client machine cause your website to load slowly? Maybe on a Pentium III, but todays machines wont have an issue.

Comment: @Chris Pietschmann: "Today's machines" still have a slow internet connection through slow routers.  The throttling occurs at the desktop.  An animated cursor is a bad example, I'll remove that, but the more web sites that are open, the less bandwidth is available.